# How can I use expect to reply to an SSH login prompt?

Tags: linux, ssh, expect

I need to create an autologin script for an ssh mount I have created in fstab.

I know that you should use secure key authentication to do this but in this case it is not possible as the server does not allow it so I need to create a bash script to enter the password when prompted.

I have tried with

```
spawn mount /media/SSH-MUSIC

expect "*?assword:*"

send "password\r"
```

But I cannot get it working.

The fstab entry is as follows

sshfs#user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/public/02.MUSIC /media/SSH-MUSIC fuse port=2223,noauto,users,allow_other,uid=1001,gid=1001,rw 0 0

Can someone please provide a working script that allows me to autologin. I have tried various suggestions from googling but been unable to get it to work.

Comment: That's not a Bash script, it's an `expect` script.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ssh`, you can either use a password, or use a public/private key set. If you use a public/private key, you can use `ssh` to another computer without having to enter in a password:

- You need to run `ssh-keygen` on both systems. This creates a directory `$HOME/.ssh` on your computer. Inside, will be two files: One is a public key, and one is a private key. In mine, the private key is called `id_rsa` and the public key is called `id_rsa.pub`. This is the default for Linux and Mac OS X.
- Once you create these files on both systems, you need to take your *public* key and paste it into a file called `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This will give the remote computer your public key, so it can identify you.

Once that is done, you should be able to use `ssh` without requiring a password which makes writing scripts that use `ssh` much, much easier.

Comment: Sorry, I already explained in the opening lines that it is not possible to do this on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the sshpass utility. I think this is easier than the spawn expect.

Comment: How do i specify the port number? I can't find in the manual how to pass it.

Comment: add port after hostname, like that: example.com:1234

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It says "unable to resolve hostname"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're omitting end of line char (\n) in your script, your third line should look like this:

```
send "password\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Expect *generally* requires "\r" as a line terminator on expected input, and "\r\n" on output. In this case, though, you don't really need to scan for the carriage return character on your input; it will work just as well with a simpler regular expression.

You can probably make this work as a one-liner. For example:

```
expect -c 'spawn mount /media/SSH-MUSIC
           expect "assword:" {send "password\r\n"}
           interact'
```

You need the **interact** command to return control of the spawned process to the user after the scripted commands complete.

Comment: the script appears to execute ok but then if I tried to list the contents of the directory I get "ls: cannot access SSH-MUSIC: Transport endpoint is not connected". The attributes of the directory have ? next to them. This doesn't happen during a manual mount and won't even partially mount on an incorrect passwrd.